# How to check if file-encoding is correct (corresponding to the country/codepages)?

Tags: c#, text, encoding, character-encoding, codepages

How can i check a txt-file if it contains only valid characters, corresponding to the country-codepage?

because they get transfered to a linux-system, so every character has to be in the codepage

through searching over google i couldnt found anything helpfull

Is there a "clean" way to check this or are there only "dirty" (static) ways to do this?

**Update:** the situation is this that i have to check resource-files that contains the translations for a application. These files were translated in different countrys, so it could easy happen that a wrong character was typed in and later the application can't display it correct. Windows always searches for the nearly same-looking character, but linux doesnt. Thats the point.

Comment: I can't say I really understand your question, but it _sounds_ like [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). How about using UTF-8 everywhere and moving on to solving real problems?

Comment: hmm.. added the description of my situation that i have. I can't change the application thats running in the linux-machine, i only have influence to the resource-files

Comment: Sounds like you need to specify that the translators must give you UTF8 files with a BOM to double-check. If the data is using the wrong code page you could get characters that appear to be valid but are in fact the wrong characters (if you are using ANSI text, which you must be if you're using a code page) and no amount of automated checking will spot those.

Comment: There are plenty of countries, especially in Eastern Asia, where there is not a single dominant 8-bit encoding.  So you'd better forget about countries and focus on code pages instead.

Comment: yes, thats true. but in my case i can generally say, if it comes from austria, it has exactly this ... etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said "Assume the files come with UTF-8".

In that case, assume that you can read the file into a C# string or array of strings.

For example, if you have a `byte[]` array you can convert to C# UTF16 string like so:

```
var text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes);
```

Or you could (using the UTF8 encoding) read it directly from a file into a C# string. Lets assume you can do that bit yourself.

Now - given you have a C# string - you can use a `Encoding.GetEncoding()` with a code page parameter and a `EncoderExceptionFallback` and a `DecoderExceptionFallback` to check whether the string is valid in that particular code page, like so:

```
public static bool IsStringValidForCodePage(string text, int codePage)
{
    var encoder = Encoding.GetEncoding(codePage, new EncoderExceptionFallback(), new DecoderExceptionFallback());

    try
    {
        encoder.GetBytes(text);
    }

    catch (EncoderFallbackException)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The following example uses the Greek Pi character, "π", which is valid in code page 1253 (Greek) and invalid in code page 1252 (Latin 1).

```
string pi = "π"; // Mmmm. I like pi.

if (IsStringValidForCodePage(pi, 1252))
    Console.WriteLine("Pi is ok in 1252");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Pi is NOT ok in 1252"); // Prints NOT ok.

if (IsStringValidForCodePage(pi, 1253))
    Console.WriteLine("Pi is ok in 1253");  // Prints ok.
else
    Console.WriteLine("Pi is NOT ok in 1253");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can get the translators to give you UTF-8 text, you can use a program to convert to the desired code page. You load the string into memory, create an instance of the target `Encoding`, and then call [Encoding.GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55.aspx) to convert the string to the proper byte sequence. Read the documentation there and the linked article about character encodings to learn how to detect and handle translation errors.

**Update in response to comment:**

If you set the [Encoder.Fallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoder.fallback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property, then that method will be invoked whenever there is an error converting a character. So if the `Encoder.Fallback` method is called, there was a conversion error. Meaning that you don't have to manually examine the converted text.

Character set conversion can be a difficult problem. I strongly suggest that you read the article [Character Encoding in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404377.aspx).

Comment: but even with this solution i would have to look if it is correct with my (physically) eyes. isnt there a programatically way to detect if only valid characters were used? Assumed the files come with UTF-8. A simple true or false would be a OK